# Basic Questions about splitting fields

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Question about Splitting Fields

If $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over the field F, then we know that the field in  particular $\frac{F[x]}{\langle p(x)\rangle}$ is extension field of degree $n$ and contains 'a' root of $p(x)$.

But I am wondering if the same  field $\frac{F[x]}{\langle p(x)\rangle}$ contains all the $n$ roots of $p(x)$?

I know if it is true, then I must use the fact that it is irreducible. But I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Think it through. For example in the case $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $p(x)=x^3-2$.

Comment: oh, thats a question about normality I was asking. Got it. The field $\mathbb{Q}({2}^\frac13)$ doesn't contain other roots of $x^3-2$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, then when we say that $\frac{F[x]}{<p(x)>}$ contain a root of $p(x)$, then which root are we talking about?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, or I should ask in which cases it will be true that it contains all the roots?

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for delimiters, not `<` and `>`.

Comment: If $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbf{F}$, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two roots of $p(x)$, the fields $\mathbf{F}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbf{F}(\beta)$ are isomorphic over $F$. There is no way to say "which root" you are adding without being in an extension that already has the roots, because the roots are algebraically  indistinguishable. That means that $\mathbf{F}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ contains a root, and you can embed it into a given splitting field sending the root $x+(p(x))$ to whatever one you want. Algebraically, you can't tell the difference between $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$,

Comment: The field $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ always contains the root $x+\langle p(x)\rangle$. It may also contain other roots of $p(x)$, but that doesn't always happen. Arturo summarized nicely what you should think about that.

Comment: If the polynomial $p(x) $ is of degree $2$ then the extension contains both the roots. Why? Because the sum of those two roots lies in $F$(and hence in any extension of $F$ as well). But if the degree is greater than $2$ this is not guaranteed. There are interesting cases like cyclotomic polynomials where the extension contains all the roots.

Answer (score 0):

Extension which contains all the roots of an irreducible polynomials over the base field once they contain one root are called Normal extensions,in general there are non-normal extension,for a concrete example ,consider the field $\mathbb{Q}$ and the irreducible polynomial $p(x)=x^{3}-2$,then $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$,this extension is contained in $\mathbb{R}$ so it cannot contains the two complex roots of $P$.of course it could be the case that an extension contains all the roots of some irreducible polynomials but not all the roots of other polynomials.Remark that every quadratic extension is normal.

Comment: this wasn't my question tho

Comment: @permutation_matrix u wrote in your post :"but I'am wondering... all the n-roots of $p(x) $? And I gave a counterexample!!then I talked about normal extension, which are directly related to your Question!!